# Opencart VqMod Error

Tags: opencart, vqmod

i have opencart 1.5.5.1 web site with VqMod(latest)
Vqmod running fine but i had a problem with one xml file.

xlm file has following lines

```xml
<file name="admin/view/template/common/header.tpl">
    <operation>               
        <search position="replace" offset="8"><![CDATA[
            <ul class="right" style="display: none;">
        ]]></search>                        
        <add><![CDATA[
            <ul class="right" style="display: none;">
                <li id="store"><a onClick="window.open('<?php echo $store; ?>');" class="top">
```

but result was shown below.

```
File Name    : admin/view/template/common/header.tpl(5)
VQModObject::applyMod - SEARCH NOT FOUND (ABORTING MOD): <ul class="right" style="display: none;">
```

there is a line `<ul class="right" style="display: none;">`in header.tpl but xml code is not working

Comment: you can search value for replace this value is not exist on header.tpl

Comment: Thanks but the value is exist On Header.tpl

Comment: finally i get solution for your Question for replace your some value on admin header see the code access direct on your vqmode.

Comment: i tried your code and its working on my setup, it might be possible ( i am not sure how vqmod tackle this problem) that line you are searching is already replaced by some other vqmod, so check in your vqcache header.tpl that this line exist or not

Answer (score 0):

Add this code for your replace you want hear:

```
<file name="admin/view/template/common/header.tpl">
    <operation>
        <search position="replace"><![CDATA[
            <li id="store"><a href="<?php echo $store; ?>" target="_blank" class="top"><?php echo $text_front; ?></a>
        ]]></search>
        <add><![CDATA[
                <li id="store"><a onClick="window.open('<?php echo $store; ?>');" class="top"><?php echo $text_front; ?></a>
        ]]>
        </add>
    </operation>
</file>
```

Comment: Thanks I ll try and gibi an answer. But What wrong with My code

Comment: you can replace <ul class="right" style="display: none;"> this to your code but actual value is not replaced <li id="store">.... so just replace line with <li id="store">.... i have use.

Comment: I tested but result is same, not working! maybe there is a different problem. The line could not be found by vqmod

Comment: you can use cloud fare so remove whole cache? or this one tested i my site.

Comment: I clear my cache before and now and the code is running yesterday. I installed different extension and now it's not running! i spend all of my day but I can't solve the problem!

Answer (score 0):

This value " `<ul class="right" style="display: none;">`" is not exactly on this file
admin/view/template/common/header.tpl

Perhaps any other extension changes this file.

Also, you can try to quit this part - offset="8"   , here:

```
<search position="replace" offset="8">
```

replace for:

```
<search position="replace">
```

I tried this, and it is good.